# Can an actor be called to inaugurate masjid

Tags: hadith-interpretation, masjid, men, ibadah, tv

Ãsak
Recently I heard a news in which one Turkish TV actor is invited to Pakistan for the mosque inauguration. As Mosque is a place of worship not a entertainment place to inaugurate with actors. And people of that place are happy to welcome him.  The Prophet SAW said a time will come people will built beautiful and elegant mosques but their hearts will be empty, no faith will be left in them. I want to know whether is it a right thing or wrong to call TV actors for inauguration and advertising the mosque.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem is here. The actor is being asked to help inaugurate a mosque - not perform there. The latter is haram, the former is fine. It would be strange though if there were no religious clerics on hand to lead the ceremonies.

Comment: But it shows that the mosque committee is attracted towards the acting industry which I think they are getting attracted more towards the worldly pleasures and reduce in religious beliefs and faith. And it is not sure whether that actor is purely religious.  Instead of actor they should have invited a religious scholar